# why the sed command is not replacing the text

Tags: bash, sed

updated code in which i got my sed command runnning, but the actual part of finding the fname and replacing with fname1 is not actually happening
    3)

```
    echo " Enter Student id number you would like to modify"
    read sID
    grep ^$sID stud
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo " The student id entered, does not exist"
    else
    echo " Enter the students first name that is being changed and than their new name to be: "
    read fName
    read fName1
    sed -i s/'$fname'/'$fname1'/g stud
    echo " Enter the students last name: "
    read lName
    echo " Enter the gender of the student(M for male or F for female): "
    read gndr
    echo " Enter the date of birth of the student(formate equals mm/dd/yr): "
    read dob
    echo " Enter the status of the student(freshman, sophomore, junior, or senior): "
    read sts
    echo " Enter the gpa of this student: "
    read gpa
    fi
;;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new to bash and using grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002485/new-to-bash-and-using-grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: remove the single quotes.

putting the variables inside the single quotes makes them not be expanded to their values but to use the literal values in quotes.

so considering a=1:

```
echo '$a'
```

echoes: $a

while:

```
echo $a ${a} "$a"
```

echoes: 1 1 1

I think the quotes are there because you could be trying to do it in a more usual form instead:

```
sed -i 's/'$fname'/'$fname1'/g' stud
```

but you should use:

```
sed -i "s/$fname/$fname1/g" stud
```

to keep it simple and because this way the command will not fail if there is a blank space in the variables, however it could fail if there is another non alphanumeric character used by sed.

REFERENCE:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: thanks for the advice and now im getting this error sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: im trying to use sed to find the name within the file and than replace it with the new name that user enters, sorry the command im in is /home/michael/cosc350/Practice/stud

Comment: :) ... I can't see the content of your home directory. I've asked what is the current sed command that is giving you that error. the question is really basic and you should try to read the manual and see the examples before ask as that would be more effective to learn. anyway, about that downvote, it wasn't me... :)

Comment: error code is this sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s' is this

Comment: haha not to worried about the down vote more so understanding the topic

Comment: There is something wrong with your sed command but I can't say what is it if you don't paste the command as is now here.

Comment: Add the quotes as I did in the last example, that is the right way, I gotta go now.

Comment: ok if you have time tonight or tomorrow my command is just as you typed above and still saying sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'

Comment: It was missing a whitespace before. fixed now.

Comment: so when the code is executed from the script (/bin/sed -i.bak 's/$fName/$fName1/g' stud.txt) the terminal does not throw any complaints and or issues. But the actual process never happens (the fname entered is not changed to fname1) and this is when trying to pass a variable. But if go to my terminal and execute just the sed line above and change the ($fname to Michael and $fname1 to Cody) the actual process happens in the text file and changes but not when ran from the script

Comment: The names in bash are case sensitive. So $fName is not the same as $fname. Check if you are using exactly the same variable name on the read and on the sed command.

Comment: yes same variables names, also my profesor was looking at and the code was working on his mac and not on my linux ubuntu edition